# Displaying an item of actionbar when a Fragment is visible true?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I have a chat and this chat is a Fragment(ChatFrag). I open this fragment from an item in my actionbar. This item is setted visible false and it will visible true when the BattleRoomFrag(fragment) is visible because ChatFrag only works in this room (BattleRoomFrag).

How can I do it ?

To do it I'm trying this.

**custom_drawer_layout**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.CustomDrawerLayout" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>


<!--Chat Button Item -->
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_chat"
    android:icon="@drawable/batalha_icon_chat"
    android:title="Chat"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:visible="false"

    />
```

**ActionBarActivity**

```
public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            selectedItem(0);
        }       
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.btmenu, R.string.nomeActionBar){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);                
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };      
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);

        tl = tlf = getTitle();      
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }




    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }

    /** necessario */
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         FragmentTransaction ft;
         Fragment frag;

         if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_chat){
             frag = new ChatFrag();
             ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
             ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag, "ChatFrag");
             ft.addToBackStack("back");
             ft.commit();
         }

         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }


     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);

        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(lv);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);

        BattleRoomFrag brf = (BattleRoomFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("BattleRoomFrag");
        MenuItem m = menu.getItem(R.id.action_chat);
        if(brf != null && brf.isVisible()){
            m.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            m.setVisible(false);
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: why don't you load different menu file on loading chat fragment ?

Comment: sorry, but I can't understand you. what did you say ?

Comment: Try this: In fragment constructor you can set setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateOptionsMenus inflate fragment menu inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_frag, menu);  (Create custom menu for your chat_frag.

Comment: @lobi you say to create other menu item ? Because I already have a menu works fine in my actionbar. My problem is only with item `action_chat`. I want to change this item to visible true when BattleRoomFrag is visible.

Comment: In @lobi's example, you would move the `action_chat` item to a separate menu xml, `chat_frag`. In the Fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, the `inflate()` call will add it to the base menu created by the Activity.

Comment: I posted my CustomDrawerLayout. Look at the method onCreateOptionsMenu I already inflate the custom_drawer_layout

Comment: Whichever menu item you want visible only with a certain Fragment, move to its own menu xml. (I guess you'd want something like `battle_frag`, not `chat_frag`; I misread.) Inflating that menu in the Fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will add it to the menu created in the Activity when that Fragment is active. Also, you can remove the Activity's `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method.

Comment: wow..very nice. I didn't know that is possible. Works fine. Thanks a lot. Could you create an answer to check V ?

Comment: Excellent! Glad you got it working. I think @lobi should get the credit for this one, though, if they'd like to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: In fragment constructor you can set setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateOptionsMenus inflate fragment menu inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_frag, menu); (Create custom menu for your chat_frag)